TextFormField and BLoC - simple feature but it just doesn't work in all use cases
In my special situation (which I guess isn't so special) I have a save button in the app bar and a form in the body. Now I am trying to get the content of a text form field forwarded to the BLoC via an event.
onChanged is not my preferred solution, because a fast typer might overload the emitting of new states, when each character is sent as an event to the BLoC.
onSubmitted also doesn't work when I tab on a different field or button without entering Enter (if I am not mistaken - at least there were scenarios where it didn't work.
focusNode with addListner works better, except: when I tab the save button of the app bar, it first saves and then executes the code of the Listener. This even happens when I sleep the execution of the save button.
The execution prints JOBEDITVIEW WIDGET.ONCHANGE change when focussing the field and then JOBEDITVIEW saving and JOBEDITVIEW WIDGET.ONCHANGE change when tabbing the save button.
How are you guys solving this?
my app bar looks like this:
return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(widget.isEditable
          ? Icons.save
          : Icons.edit),
      onPressed: () {
        sleep(Duration(milliseconds:2000));
        if (widget.isEditable) {
          if (widget.formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            keyJobEditView.currentState!.saveForm(bloc);
          }
        } else bloc.add(JobEditRequested());
      },
    );

keyJobEditView.currentState!.saveForm(bloc); is a function inside the State class
void saveForm(JobEditBloc bloc) {
    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
print("JOBEDITVIEW saving");
      bloc.add(JobEditDataSubmitted(jobData: jobUpdated!));
    }
}

Node Listener
    nodeNotes.addListener(() {
      if (!nodeNotes.hasFocus && _notesCtrl.text.length > 0) {
        widget.onChanged((startAfter, finishBefore, fixedDurationInMin,
        _notesCtrl.text));
print("JOBEDITVIEW WIDGET.ONCHANGE change");
      }});

node within the textformfield
TextFormField(
    controller: _notesCtrl,
    focusNode: nodeNotes,
),

As requested, more context with the flow, though only the most relevant lines of code
class JobEditViewState extends State<JobEditView>{
  JobEditViewmodel? jobUpdated;
  late TextEditingController notesCtrl = TextEditingController();
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar( // ------------------------------------------------------- AppBar
          actions: <Widget>[
            BlocBuilder<JobEditBloc, JobEditState>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, JobEditState state) {
                return _AppBarAction(isEditable: state.isEditable, formKey: formKey,);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: BlocBuilder<JobEditBloc, JobEditState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              final JobEditBloc bloc = context.read<JobEditBloc>();
              jobUpdated = bloc.state.jobData!;
              List<Widget> sections = [
                _ScheduleData(bloc: bloc, 
                    isEditable: state.isEditable,
                    startAfter: jobUpdated!.startAfter,
                    finishBefore: jobUpdated!.finishBefore,
                    fixedDurationInMin: jobUpdated!.fixedDuration,
                    notes: jobUpdated!.notes,
                    onChanged: (data) => setState(() {
                      jobUpdated = jobUpdated!.copyWith(
                          startAfter: () => data.$1,
                          finishBefore: () => data.$2,
                          fixedDuration: () => data.$3,
                          notes: () => data.$4
                      );
                      bloc.add(JobEditDataUpdated(jobData: jobUpdated!));
                    })),
                _DescrData(bloc: bloc,
                    isEditable: state.isEditable,
                    title: jobUpdated!.title,
                    description: jobUpdated!.description,
                    onChanged: (data) => setState(() {
                      jobUpdated = jobUpdated!.copyWith(
                        title: () => data.$1,
                        description: () => data.$2,
                      );
                      bloc.add(JobEditDataUpdated(jobData: jobUpdated!));
                    })),
                _TasksData(bloc: bloc, 
                    isEditable: state.isEditable,
                    tasks: jobUpdated!.tasks,
                    furtherTasks: jobUpdated!.furtherTasks ?? [[], [], [], []],
                    onChanged: (List<List<TaskFormTilesViewModel>> data) => setState(() {
                      jobUpdated = jobUpdated!.copyWith(tasks: () => data);
                    }))
              ];
              return Container(
                  child: Form(
                      key: formKey,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: sections.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return sections[index];
                          })));
            },),
    );
  }
  void saveForm(JobEditBloc bloc) {
    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      bloc.add(JobEditDataSubmitted(jobData: jobUpdated!));
    }
  }
}

// =============================================================================

class _TasksDataState extends State<_TasksData>{
  late List<List<TaskFormTilesViewModel>> tasks;
  late List<List<TaskFormTilesViewModel>> furtherTasks;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tasks = widget.tasks;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final int tasksLength = widget.tasks.length;
    final int rows = tasksLength + (widget.isEditable ? widget.furtherTasks.length : 0);
    furtherTasks = widget.furtherTasks;
    return Material(type: MaterialType.transparency, child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
//        itemCount: widget.tasks.length,
        itemCount: rows,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) =>
        (!widget.isEditable || i < tasksLength)
            ? TaskFormTiles(
                tasks: widget.tasks[i],
                taskTypeIdx: i,
                bloc: widget.bloc,
                // send pointers pointing to the event needed by child widget
                taskSelectedEvent: (int j) => JobEditTaskActiveToggled(i, j, true),
                isEditable: widget.isEditable,
                tasksReturned: (List<TaskFormTilesViewModel> tasksReturned)
                => setState(() {
                  tasks[i] = tasksReturned;
                  widget.onChanged(tasks);
            }))
            : TaskFormTiles(
                tasks: widget.furtherTasks[i-tasksLength],
                taskTypeIdx: i-tasksLength,
                bloc: widget.bloc,
                // send pointers pointing to the event needed by child widget
                taskSelectedEvent: (int j) => JobEditTaskActiveToggled(i-tasksLength, j, false),
                isEditable: widget.isEditable,
                tasksReturned: (List<TaskFormTilesViewModel> tasksReturned)
                => setState(() {
                  furtherTasks[i-tasksLength] = tasksReturned;
            }))
    ));
  }
}

// =============================================================================

class _TaskFormTilesState extends State<TaskFormTiles2> {
  late List<TaskFormTilesViewModel> tasks;
  late final bool showOnRequestBox;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    showOnRequestBox = (widget.taskSelectedEvent(0) is! JobEditEvent);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    tasks = widget.tasks;
    //  final t = widget.taskSelectedEvent(2,2);
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: tasks.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) =>
            ListTile(
              trailing: GestureDetector(
                  child: tasks[i].selected ? Icon(Icons.check) : SizedBox()),
              onTap: () {
                if (widget.isEditable) {
                  widget.bloc.add(widget.taskSelectedEvent(i));
                }
              },
            )
    );
  }
}

And the BLoC
class JobEditBloc extends Bloc<JobEditEvent, JobEditState> {
  JobEditBloc() : super(JobEditState()) {
    on<JobEditDataRequested>(_onJobEditDataRequested);
    on<JobEditDataRequested2>(_onJobEditDataRequested2);
    on<JobEditRequested>(_onJobEditRequested2);
    on<JobEditRequestToggledEvent>(_onJobEditRequestToggledEvent);
    on<JobEditTaskDeselected>(_onJobEditTaskSelected);
    on<JobEditTaskActiveToggled>(_onJobEditTaskActiveToggled);
    on<JobEditDataUpdated>(_onJobEditDataUpdated2);
    on<JobEditDataSubmitted>(_onJobEditDataSubmitted);
  }
  
  late List<List<TaskFormTilesViewModel>> masterTasks;
  late List<List<TaskFormTilesViewModel>> furtherTasks;

  _onJobEditDataUpdated2(JobEditDataUpdated event,
      Emitter<JobEditState> emit) {
    emit(state.copyWith(
      //validationData: () => formValidation,
      jobData: () => event.jobData,
    ));
  }

  _onJobEditTaskActiveToggled(JobEditTaskActiveToggled event,
      Emitter<JobEditState> emit) async {
    final List<List<TaskFormTilesViewModel>> returnedTasks = state.jobData!.tasks;
    late JobEditState newState;

    if (event.isMasterTask) {
      masterTasks[event.outerIdx][event.innerIdx] =
          masterTasks[event.outerIdx][event.innerIdx].copyWith(
              selected: () => !masterTasks[event.outerIdx][event.innerIdx].selected
          );
      newState = state.copyWith(
          jobData: () => state.jobData!.copyWith(tasks: () => masterTasks),
          toggleToRebuild: () => !state.toggleToRebuild);
    } else {
      furtherTasks[event.outerIdx][event.innerIdx] =
          furtherTasks[event.outerIdx][event.innerIdx].copyWith(
              selected: () => !furtherTasks[event.outerIdx][event.innerIdx].selected
          );
      newState = state.copyWith(
          jobData: () => state.jobData!.copyWith(furtherTasks: () => furtherTasks),
          toggleToRebuild: () => !state.toggleToRebuild);
    }
    emit(newState);
  }

  _onJobEditDataSubmitted(JobEditDataSubmitted event,
      Emitter<JobEditState> emit) {
    final List<TaskFormTilesViewModel> tasksFlattened = [];
    final List<PropertyTask> jobTasks = [];
    final List<List<TaskFormTilesViewModel>> tasks = event.jobData.tasks;
    tasks[3].removeWhere((t) => !(t!.selected ?? false)
        && t.taskType == PropertyTaskTypes.onRequest);
    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
      tasksFlattened.addAll(tasks[i]);
    }
    final List<List<TaskFormTilesViewModel>>? furtherTasks = event.jobData.furtherTasks;
    if (furtherTasks != null) {
      for (final selection in furtherTasks) {
        for (final task in selection) {
          if (task.selected) {
            tasksFlattened.add(task);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    for (final t in tasksFlattened) {
      jobTasks.addAll(allPropertyTasks.where((at) => at.id == t.id));
    }

    final JobEntry jobEntry = event.jobData.toDomain(jobTasks);
    _jobCalendarRepository.storeCalendarJob(jobEntry: jobEntry);
    emit(state.copyWith(
      //validationData: () => formValidation,
      jobData: () => event.jobData,
      status: () => DataTransStatus.saved,
    ));
  }
}


tried the official tutorials from bloclibrary.dev/ site? they have couple of samples where TextField is used

yes. They are using onChanged.  However, besides me not wanting to run all the BLoC code each time when typing a character, events in a sequence <0.2s may cause hiccups. I think they softened this issue a bit, however, I do not want to assess the current capability of rapid events, since I would prefer passing the final text field, anyway.

In the problem description I left out most of the context to keep it simple. I have text inputs and tiles to select. Worse, the tiles are not only selected/deselected but also differ in preselected inside a data master vs otherwise available. Long story short, the tile selection runs via BLoC and each tile selection rebuilds the form.  Reusing the state data would then overwrite the text fields with old data unless I get the text to the BLoC before final submit. Maybe some fuzzy logic around data updates could help, but I was hoping for a more straight forward logic.Hope I got the intent clear

can you post a complete but minimal code to follow (just main with your form and bloc)?

Ok, I edited the question. I took as much code out as I could, but still long. I hope not too confusing, because I tried already several approaches what might have left traces in the logic.

I solved it with a work around, but maybe still someone has an idea how to better overcome this. I made the experience in the past that you have issues when not passing each change of a character within a text field to a BLoC, using save buttons might miss the last edited field. In case of pure form fields this may not be an issue, but when not using form or when having a slightly difficult data management approach (like me in this example) it might well cause an issue.
I now left all data changes other than tile selections within the State widget and I only process the tile selection within the Bloc widget. Not so nice to separate the data updating in 2 places - but it works at least...
